# Why does the origin of the second ball not attached to the first ball?

Tags: oop, processing

I was reading the book [The Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-3-oscillation/), where Exercise 3.12 asked me to implement a double pendulum.

```
class Pendulum {

  PVector origin, location;

  float r; // arm length
  float angle;
  float aVelocity;
  float aAcceleration;
  float damping;

  Pendulum(PVector origin_, float r_) {
    origin = origin_.get();
    location = new PVector();
    r = r_;
    angle = PI/3;
    aVelocity = 0;
    aAcceleration = 0;
    damping = 0.995;
  }

  void go() {
    update();
    display();
  }

  void update() {
    float gravity = 0.4;
    aAcceleration = (-1 * gravity / r) * sin(angle);
    aVelocity += aAcceleration;
    angle += aVelocity;
    aVelocity *= damping;
    location.set(r*sin(angle), r*cos(angle));
    location.add(origin);
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    line(origin.x, origin.y, location.x, location.y);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(location.x, location.y, 20, 20);
  }
}

Pendulum p, p2;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  p = new Pendulum(new PVector(width/2, 0), 150);
  p2 = new Pendulum(p.location, 100);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  p.go();
  p2.go();
}
```

So in the `setup` function, I set the `origin` of `p2` to be the `location` of `p1`. However, the `origin` of `p2` appeared on the position (0, 0). How should I fix this? I have tried to set a temporary variable for `p2` but that's not convenient.

Comment: In the ctor you create a new `PVector` but never copy `origin_` into it. https://processing.org/reference/PVector_copy_.html

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `location` is the location of the ball, `origin` is the starting point of the rope, so they are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do,
but in the constructor:

```
Pendulum(PVector origin_, float r_) {
    origin = origin_.get();
    location = new PVector(); <-- here you set the location to a new vector
    ...
}
```

And you directly use the location in here:

```
void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  p = new Pendulum(new PVector(width/2, 0), 150);
  p2 = new Pendulum(p.location, 100); <-- here
}
```

which is the new location created. i suppose that's your problem you should be looking into.